# Devise / ActionMailer sending duplicate emails for registration confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, duplicates, actionmailer, confirmation-email

My rails application uses devise to handle registration, authentication, etc. I'm using the confirmable module. The bug is this– when a user registers with email, Devise is sending two confirmation emails with different confirmation links. One link works, the other directs the user to an error page.

Devise spits out a message associated with the error: "Confirmation token is invalid" and takes the user to the Resend Confirmation Email page.

I'm hosting with heroku and using sendgrid to send the emails. **update:** The bug also occurs on localhost.

I have no idea where the root of this bug is, and this might be more code than what you need to see:



**models/user.rb**

```
...

devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :omniauthable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, 
     :confirmable, :authentication_keys => [:login]

...

## callbacks
after_create :account_created

# called after the account is first created
def account_created

  # check if this activiy has already been created
  if !self.activities.where(:kind => "created_account").blank?
    puts "WARNING: user ##{self.id} already has a created account activity!"
    return
  end

  # update points
  self.points += 50
  self.save

  # create activity
  act = self.activities.new
  act.kind = "created_account"
  act.created_at = self.created_at
  act.save

end

...

def confirmation_required?
  super && (self.standard_account? || self.email_changed)
end

...
```

**controllers/registrations_controller.rb**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def update
    unless @user.last_sign_in_at.nil?

      puts "--------------double checking whether password confirmation is required--"
      ## if the user has not signed in yet, we don't want to do this.

      @user = User.find(current_user.id)
      # uncomment if you want to require password for email change
      email_changed = @user.email != params[:user][:email]
      password_changed = !params[:user][:password].empty?

      # uncomment if you want to require password for email change
      # successfully_updated = if email_changed or password_changed

      successfully_updated = if password_changed
        params[:user].delete(:current_password) if params[:user][:current_password].blank?
        @user.update_with_password(params[:user])
      else
        params[:user].delete(:current_password)
        @user.update_without_password(params[:user])
      end

      if successfully_updated
        # Sign in the user bypassing validation in case his password changed
        sign_in @user, :bypass => true
        if email_changed
          flash[:blue] = "Your account has been updated! Check your email to confirm your new address. Until then, your email will remain unchanged."
        else
          flash[:blue] = "Account info has been updated!"
        end
        redirect_to edit_user_registration_path
      else
        render "edit"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**controllers/omniauth_callbacks_controller**

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

    def facebook
        user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    if user.persisted?
      flash.notice = "Signed in!"

      # if the oauth_token is expired or nil, update it...
      if (DateTime.now > (user.oauth_expires_at || 99.years.ago) )
        user.update_oauth_token(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
      end

      sign_in_and_redirect user
    else
      session["devise.user_attributes"] = user.attributes
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
    end
end
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
...

devise_for :users, controllers: {omniauth_callbacks: "omniauth_callbacks", 
                                :registrations => "registrations"}

...
```

I'm happy to provide more information if needed. I'm also open to customizing/overriding the devise mailer behavior, but I don't know how to go about that.

Much thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Solved!

I was able to override Devise::Mailer and force a stack trace to find out exactly what was causing duplicate emails. Devise::Mailer#confirmation_instructions was being called twice, and I found out that the problem was with my :after_create callback, shown below:

**in models/user.rb...**

```
after_create :account_created

# called after the account is first created
def account_created

...

  # update points
  self.points += 50
  self.save

...

end
```

Calling self.save somehow caused the mailer to be triggered again. I solved the problem by changing when the points are added. I got rid of the after_create call and overrode the confirm! method in devise to look like this:

```
def confirm!
  super
  account_created
end
```

So now the user record doesn't get modified (adding points) until after confirmation. No more duplicate emails!

Comment: Thanks for this great tip! After some experimentation I've settled with overriding the `generate_confirmation_token` method in my user model instead of overriding `confirm!`. It has the advantage that the original callback / the function is called when or instantly after the user is created. With `confirm!` it would be called when the user clicks the confirmation link in the email (which might be some time after signup).

Answer (score 9):

I originally went with Thomas Klemm's answer but I went back to look at this when I had some spare time to try and figure out what was happening as it didn't feel right.

I tracked the 'problem' down and noticed that it only happens when :confirmable is set in your devise (User) model and reconfirmable is enabled in the devise initializer - which in hindsight makes a lot of sense because essentially in the after_create we ARE changing the User model, although we aren't changing the email address - I suspect Devise may do this because the account isn't confirmed yet, but in any case **it is easy to stop the second email just by calling self.skip_reconfirmation!** in the after_create method.

I created a sample rails project with a couple of tests just to ensure the correct behaviour. Below are the key excerpts. If you have far too much time on your hands, you can see the project here: https://github.com/richhollis/devise-reconfirmable-test

app/models/User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  after_create :add_attribute

  private

  def add_attribute
    self.skip_reconfirmation!
    self.update_attributes({ :status => 200 }, :without_protection => true)
  end
end
```

initializers/devise.rb

```
# Use this hook to configure devise mailer, warden hooks and so forth.
# Many of these configuration options can be set straight in your model.
Devise.setup do |config|

  ..
  ..

  # If true, requires any email changes to be confirmed (exactly the same way as
  # initial account confirmation) to be applied. Requires additional unconfirmed_email
  # db field (see migrations). Until confirmed new email is stored in
  # unconfirmed email column, and copied to email column on successful confirmation.
  config.reconfirmable = true

  ..
  ..

end
```

spec/models/user_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  subject(:user) { User.create(:email => 'nobody@nobody.com', :password => 'abcdefghijk') }

  it "should only send one email during creation" do
    expect {
      user
    }.to change(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries, :count).by(1)
  end

  it "should set attribute in after_create as expected" do
    user.status.should eq(200)
  end

end
```

Running the rspec tests to ensure only one email is sent confirms the behaviour:

> ..
>
> Finished in 0.87571 seconds 2 examples, 0 failures

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your great solution, Stephen! I've tried it and it works perfectly to hook into the `confirm!` method. However, in this case, the function is being called (as the name says) when the user clicks the confirmation link in the email he receives.

An alternative is to hook into the `generate_confirmation_token` method, so your method is called directly when the confirmation token is created and the email is sent.

```
# app/models/user.rb
def generate_confirmation_token
  make_owner_an_account_member
  super # includes a call to save(validate: false), 
        # so be sure to call whatever you like beforehand
end

def make_owner_an_account_member
  self.account = owned_account if owned_account?
end
```

[Relevant source of the confirmation module](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb).